# Sweet roll dough

Tags: baking

My dough was really pourable even after raising !  I added a lot more flour to be able to handle it !  I have made this before , what did I do wrong ?

Comment: Sharon, welcome! Please [edit] your post with more details - especially the ratios and method you used. The more details you give, the better the answer community can answer. The [tour], the [help] and especially [ask] should help you get started here.

Answer (score 2):

Usually, when dough doesn't hold it's shape (slips or pours between fingers if you hold it up) it's because it didn't have enough "structure". This is obtained by kneading the dough longer. I usually knead bread dough for about 10 min.  However, when doing sweet doughs which are a stickier (wetter) dough, I often have to knead a little more.  It is more difficult to work with, as you don't want to ruin all your work by adding more flour. So, as long as your initial ratio of ingredients was precise, all you needed was a little more kneading before you let it rise, and your dough will become smoother and elastic and hold together for you.